# How to change an entity of kind Model to Polymodel without losing existing entities?

Tags: google-app-engine, django-models

I am using App Engine and App Engine Patch for Django

I have a class defined in my models that was inheriting from `db.Model`. I've now changed it to `polymodel.PolyModel`. Since making the change, my existing entities are no longer retrievable. Is there a way to access them or convert them?

What's the recommended procedure for changing an entity class's kind?

Answer (score 2):

Solved using gaebar, google app engine backup and restore. Although this isnt necessarily going to be the best solution for large datastores..

Answer (score 2):

The hassle of migrating data makes you wonder if you always want to start off with polymodel for all new entites. Answer: No. As explained [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/dab45bb7a53d3e36#).

Comment: Just to add to what you said, the explanation says that you shouldn't use polymodels unless you think you might need the functionality later on.